# Why is the promise not recognizing the variable and just returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, random, promise, es6-promise

I just started learning about promises in javascript and was playing around with this toy example

I defined a function that spits out a random number between 0 and 10 after 1 second to simulate fetching data from an API

```
function randNum() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    let num =(Math.random()) * 10 
    return num
  }, 1000)
}
```

Then I defined a function which returns a promise which is resolved if the random number > 5 and rejected if its <5

```
function myPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let myNum = randNum()
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (myNum > 5) {
        resolve(myNum)
      } else {
        reject(myNum)
      }
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

the promise is either resolved or rejected after 2 seconds ...so the value of myNum should be assigned by then ..but when I try to use the promise

```
myPromise().then((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); }).catch((myNum) => { console.log(myNum) })
```

it just returns undefined

what am i doing wrong here?? i dont really understand promises all that well

Answer (score 1):

`randNum()` doesn't explicitly return anything. It has no return statement. `let myNum = randNum()` is equivalent to `randNum(); let myNum = undefined`.

You can see it when you define and use a named function instead of an anonymous lambda function:

```
function myRand() {
  let num = Math.random() * 10;
  return num;
}

function randNum() {
  setTimeout(myRand, 1000); // There is no return statement in randNum
}
```

Either remove `setTimeout`:

```js
function randNum() {
  let num = Math.random() * 10;
  return num;
}

function myPromise(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let myNum = randNum();
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (myNum > 5) {
        resolve(myNum);
      } else {
        reject(myNum);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });
}
myPromise(10).then((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); }).catch((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); });
```

or return a `Promise`:

```js
function randNum() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let num = Math.random() * 10;
        resolve(num);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function myPromise(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    randNum().then(myNum => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (myNum > 5) {
          resolve(myNum);
        } else {
          reject(myNum);
        }
      }, 2000);
    });
  });
}
myPromise(10).then((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); }).catch((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); });
```

Using a `sleep` function with `async`/`await` is usually considered more readable:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, ms); });
}

async function randNum() {
  await sleep(1000);
  let num = Math.random() * 10;
  return num;
}

async function myPromise(val) {
  let myNum = await randNum();
  await sleep(2000);
  if (myNum > 5) {
    return myNum;
  } else {
    throw myNum;
  }
}
myPromise(10).then((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); }).catch((myNum) => { console.log(myNum); })
```

Comment: thanks for helping out....what do u mean by "randNum() doesn't return anything"? Didn't i define it to return the random number 'num' ..does the timeout function change this behavior...i will be very grateful if u could pls provide an explanation

Comment: @NishchalBhat `() => { ... }` defines an anonymous function. This function has a return statement and it returns `num`. `randNum` doesn't have a return statement.